# Glassfish SSL error - SSL connection error

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I am using the following guide to setup SSL on my glassfish server hosted in EC2.
I kept getting SSL connection error while browsing the 8181 page and there isn't any warning or error on the server log.

http://aliok.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/using-your-ssl-certificate-on-glassfish-3/

1. keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias yourdomain.com -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=www.yourdomain.com,O=Your Organization,L=Your City,S=Your State,C=Your Country Code like US, CH or TR" -keystore keystore.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
2. keytool -certreq -alias yourdomain.com -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -keypass changeit -file server.csr

Download 2 cert files from godaddy.

1. keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ~/ssl-stuff/keystore.jks -destkeystore $GLASSFISHHOME/domains/yourdomain/config/keystore.jks
2. cd $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/yourdomain/config
   keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias root -file gd_bundle.crt -keystore keystore.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
3. keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias yourdomain.com -file yourdomain.com.crt -keystore keystore.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit

then i changed the server config SSL section, certificate nickname to yourdomain.com

Comment: I followed the same guide and had the same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, been almost 2 days now i can't make it work